# Large Space between text and HTML table

Tags: html, google-forms

I have a Google form that I am trying to force to email me the results in a specific format. It works, but the table I insert has a large blank space above it that I would like to get rid of. For example:

```
Hello!

I have a purchase request that I would like to submit for review, approval, 
and processing. Please see below and attached. Thanks.


















Name:   
Ryan M  

Project Number: 
Numbers 

Project Comments:   
No Comments 

Website Link to Product:    


Cost:   


Purpose of Order:   
Test    

Document Upload:    
https://drive.google.com/file/d//view   

Date Required By:   
2017-01-13  

Confirmed Lead Time:    
teeeeeest
```

Here is the Code I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top:0px;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>

<tr>
    <td><b>Name:</b></td>
    <td>{{Name}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Project Number:</b></td>
    <td>{{Project Number}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Project Comments:</b></td>
    <td>{{Project Comments}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Website Link to Product:</b></td>
    <td>{{Website Link to Product}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Cost:</b></td>
    <td>{{Cost}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Purpose of Order:</b></td>
    <td>{{Purpose of Order}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Document Upload:</b></td>
    <td>https://drive.google.com/file/d/{{Document Upload}}/view</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Date Required By:</b></td>
    <td>{{Date Required By}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Confirmed Lead Time:</b></td>
    <td>{{Confirmed Lead Time}}</td>
</tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Any clues would be a great help. Thanks!

Comment: It's probably the data that's being passed into {{Name}}.

Comment: @RossKeddy Hm. It's possible. The {{Name}} Placeholder is fed by a dropdown answer in the form. I'll try removing it, see if that helps.

Comment: Just check/display the data somewhere to trace this back to make sure the data isn't gathering new lines. Check your welcome message and the name.

Comment: @RossKeddy No dice. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

HTML emails can be viewed in various different tools and none of them (outlook) support it the same way (CSS markup included).

The way the output looks make me think that the table is not expanding to 100%. Notice how the table cells are stacked. This could be symptomatic of your real problem, the viewport.

You might start by setting the `<html>` and `<body>` width to 100%. Try both CSS and the in-line style markup.

```
<body width="100%">
```

I'd stay away from any HTML5 options like `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width">` since you can't guarantee support in email applications.

The CSS markup might not be an option so you could try putting it all inline.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think the formatting of the email notification is just not up to the task. I tried several different combinations of table and body width, with no luck.